# Take first 5 from previous query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

If I have a query like:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

How can I select the first 5 results from *that* previous query? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$first_five = $posts->take(5)->get();
```

Or in other words, how do I get the first 5 elements in the returned object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can use `$first_five = Post::all()->take(5)->get();`

I am guessing you may be able to do this also:

```
$posts = Post::all();

$first_five = $posts->take(5);
```

Also, have a look into [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination).